# ajaxtabcontainer do full postback, how to controll it

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I use scriptManager in masterpage, because every content page is to be ajxify.

In content page, I use `UpdatePanel` and everything work fine but in case of content page where I use `TabCOntainer`, each time when I move from one tab to another tab, page is full postback.

Here one thing I notice that when I remove `ScriptManager` from master page and use in `contentPage` then `tabContainer` works fine.

What will be possible solution for such type condition?

**MASTERPAGE**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
 </head>

 <body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">

  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_Register" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
        //Update Panel work at Master Page
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


           <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="showcase" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**CONTENTPAGE**

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterDashBoard.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="messages.aspx.cs" Inherits="messages" %>

  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_msg" runat="server" >

      <ContentTemplate>

        <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="True"
                        OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged">

           <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1" ToolTip="Compose Message">

               <HeaderTemplate>
                                Compose
               </HeaderTemplate>

               <ContentTemplate>
                        Some Work

               </ContentTemplate>

   </cc1:TabPanel>

       <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2" ID="TabPanel2">

                <HeaderTemplate>
                                inbox
                </HeaderTemplate>

                 <ContentTemplate>
            SOme Work
                 </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>

      </cc1:TabContainer>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Why do you post this question again? It has only been two hours since you posted this question the first time... Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682011/ajaxtabcontainer-do-full-postback-issue-help-plz-i-stuck-here

Comment: Make sure you improve your existing post, that may help.

Comment: Please do not double post questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar use case and set `UpdateMode="Conditional"`, `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` and use `AsyncPostbackTriggers` for the `ActiveTabChanged` event. In the `ActiveTabChanged` event handler i switch visibility of the containing controls and call [`Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) on the according UpdatePanel and finally on the surrounding `UpdatePanel`. This allows furthermore to lazy-load the Tabs by loading their content only when needed.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdTabContainer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabDeliveryControl" runat="server" HeaderText="Delivery-Control">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="PnlTabDeliveryControl" runat="server" ToolTip="Delivery-Control">
                                Delivery-Control
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <SVCS:SVCSDeliveryControl id="SVCSDeliveryControl" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TabContainer1" EventName="ActiveTabChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabRepair" runat="server" HeaderText="Repair-Area" >
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="PnlTabRepair" runat="server" ToolTip="Repair-Area">
                                Repair-Area
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <SVCS:SVCSRepair id="SVCSRepair" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TabContainer1" EventName="ActiveTabChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabShipping" runat="server" HeaderText="Shipping" Visible="false">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="PnlTabShipping" runat="server" ToolTip="Shipping">
                                Shipping
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <SVCS:SVCSShipping id="SVCSShipping" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TabContainer1" EventName="ActiveTabChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                </asp:TabContainer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```